# Angular Google Maps: can't get the LatLng from click event object

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, events, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

In my app, after a click on the google map, I need to get the lat and lng information for further handling. And since the app use angularJs as the framework, I used the Angular Google Maps library for maps. My code is as following:

```
$scope.map = {
        center: {
           latitude: 37.782551,
           longitude: -122.445368
        },
        zoom: 12,
        heatLayerCallback: function (layer) {
           MockHeatLayer(layer);
        },
        showHeat: true,
        // the issue is from here
        onclick: {
            click : function(maps, event, arguments) {
                console.log(event.latLng); //return undefined 
                console.log(typeof(event)); //return string type instead of event object 
            }
        }
};
```

and HTML tag is as following:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom' events='map.onclick'>
    <ui-gmap-layer namespace="visualization" type="HeatmapLayer" show="map.showHeat" onCreated="map.heatLayerCallback"></ui-gmap-layer>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

as you can see, I set the `events` to `onclick` in the `map` array. 
But after debugging, the the `event` in the handle function is a string instead of object, so what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation,the second argument is `eventName` which is supposed to be string, because event object is in the third argument. From [docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/google-map):

> The handler function takes three parameters: 
>     1. maps: the GoogleMap
>     2. object eventName: **the name of the event** 3. arguments: **the arguments provided by Google Maps for this event type**.

So instead of `onclick: { ...` in your code, put this:

```
events: {
     click : function(maps, eventName, arguments) {
          var e = arguments[0];
          var lat = e.latLng.lat(), lng = e.latLng.lng();
          console.log("my lat is:" + lat + ", lng is:" + lng);
     }
}
```

**Update**
`events` array could also be named `onclick`, depending on the type of the event you want to handle.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Your explanation about those three arguments are very help. I used the wrong argument! But one more thing, there is no need to change the array name. events is the attribute name. I still use the onclick, and use the third argument, and it works. That for remind

Comment: Thanks for your input, I cannot find that in the docs. I will update my answer so it mentions that `events` array doesn't have to be renamed.